# Change character's size in Power BI's drill down/up

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a chart on Power BI with the X-Axis text size equal *27*. But when I *drill down* my data, I want that the *text size of X-Axis* changes to *20* and if I drill down it for a *second time*, the X-Axis text size must 15. And finally if I *drill up the* text size must changes to the previous size.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know 100% but could bet it's not possible with built-in functionality - it's tad too specific. If it's *really* important to you, the only option may be creating a custom visual.

Comment: Thank you, I asked this same question one Power Bi forum and I'm waiting for the answer. But I'm thinking like you, that it's not possible without a custom layout.